# generate non-prime numbers for a range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

we have to generate a python function to return non-prime numbers.
For example, if we pass `10` it should return `1 4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16`

Here's what I'm have tried so far:

```
def np_generator(n):
    str1 = [1]
    for num in range(2, 100):
        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2, num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    str1.append(num)
                    break
                if(len(str1)==n):
                    print(str1)
        else:
            None
        pass
```

and it's output is near to the solution:
When I pass `12` as `n` it returns:

```
1
[1]
2
[1, 4]
[1, 4]
[1, 4]
3
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 6]
4
[1, 4, 6, 8]
5
6
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
7
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12]
8
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14]
9
10
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
[1, 4, 6, 8,{-truncated-}
```

and the expected output is:

```
1
4
6
8
9
10
12
14
15
16
18
20
```

Comment: what generator does here ?

Comment: `generator ` will print out the +ve non-prime numbers from this function.

Comment: why pass generator as function argument ? if you are using why process after it ?

Comment: Hi @prashantrana I have added the `generator`'s code also, take a look, please!

Comment: But generator is *not used* in that function. Why pass it? Note you have many other errors too: a set does not have an `append` method, the while loop will never end because `n` is always greater than 1, etc.

Comment: Hi @prashantrana as I said, it's a challenge, so the generator is the locked code which we can't edit, but for testing, we can omit the `generator` argument from `np_generator` function.

Comment: Note that all your function *actually* does is yield `1` then get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman should i call `add` instead of `append`? what's wrong here? please!

Comment: Well, that would fix the error if you ever got into the else block. But you don't, because `primes` starts out empty and is never non-empty, so nothing is ever added to it.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, can you rewrite the code? please!

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, I have updated the code, take a look, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from math import sqrt
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
def yield_np(n):
    np_counter = 1
    num_to_print = 1
    while np_counter <= n:
        if num_to_print == 1 or is_prime(num_to_print) == False:
            yield num_to_print
            np_counter+=1
        num_to_print+=1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input())
    if n > 0:
        for i in yield_np(n):
            print(i)
    else:
        print()
```

Comment: Hi @ParthS007 how can I yield the non-prime numbers to the generator, so it can prints only non-prime numbers?

Comment: Try giving 10 as input. Most of the coding challenges will not ask you for a prompt. So I have not given a prompt like 'enter n value'. Just run the program and provide the input

Comment: I have added a `Latest Update` in the question, take a look, please! What I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: I don't understand your logic and why do you have nested functions?  I have given the solution for your problem.

Comment: as I said, it's a code challenge, so there I have only one function in which I have to write the complete code, that's I have adjust it in this way.

Comment: You say you have *only one function*. What's the name of that function and how many params does it take? Please provide the details

Comment: It’s locked we can not change the part below positive_integers_generator.

Comment: Ok I understood your problem. I got confused because of too much info you have provided in your question

Comment: Please provide a clear definition of `positive_integers_generator()`. Only if you provide the full definition, I can help you

Comment: I have posted the complete definition of this function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195260/discussion-between-prasanth-ganesan-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: Hi @PrasanthGanesan will you update your answer? please!

Comment: A sieve should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime (x):
    """
    check a number is prime or not
    """
    return True if x in [2,3] else not any (x % n == 0 for n in range (2, int (x ** 0.5) + 1))

def non_prime(n):
    """n = no of non prime user want"""
    non_prime =[1] # list of non prime
    value = 3 # settign counter to start 
    while len(non_prime) < n :
        """looping till  length of non prime reached to n"""           
        if not is_prime(value):
            """ if number is not prime, adding that value to non prime"""
            non_prime.append(value)
        value +=1 # incrementing value after each iteration
    return non_prime # return non prime values

    res = non_prime(10)
    print(res)
```

output

```
[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16]
```